# pymongo 3.6.1 throws error InvalidURI: The empty string is not valid username

Tags: python, pymongo

I am running into following error with pymongo 3.6.1 the same works with 3.6.0,can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this in pymongo 3.6.1 ?

CODE:-

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import os,pymongo
dbuser = os.environ.get('muser', '')
dbpass = os.environ.get('mpwd', '')
uri = 'mongodb://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@machine.company.com:27017/techautomation'.format(**locals())
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.techautomation
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 7, in <module>
    client = MongoClient(uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 468, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port, warn=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 379, in parse_uri
    user, passwd = parse_userinfo(userinfo)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 101, in parse_userinfo
    raise InvalidURI("The empty string is not valid username.")
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: The empty string is not valid username.
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty descriptive. Why do you do `os.environ.get('muser', '')`? How is not providing the environment variable `muser` acceptable? It seems the right way to fix your problem is to provide it.

Comment: @AlexHall - it is provided in the environment ,are you saying to put something like `os.environ.get('muser', 'username ')`,if I type `env` on my machine I can see the muser and mpwd,this works fine on 3.6.0 ,only with 3.6.1 it fails

Comment: Try `print(dbuser)` or `print(uri)` to see if the environment variable went through to Python. Maybe the empty string check only got added in 3.6.1.